# Create a matrix where if an element in an M×N matrix is 0, its entire row and column are set to 0

Tags: java, array, matrix

How is my implementation? Are there improvements I can make to the variable names or any edge cases I might have missed?

```
public class ZeroMatrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[][]{
                {1, 0, 2},
                {3, 4, 1}
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(setZeroes(matrix)));
    }

    private static int[][] setZeroes(int[][] matrix) {
        boolean[] rowsWithZero = new boolean[matrix.length];
        boolean[] columnsWithZero = new boolean[matrix[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    rowsWithZero[i] = true;
                    columnsWithZero[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // Iterate through the rowsWithZero array and transform all rows with 0 to 0
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsWithZero.length; i++) {
            if (rowsWithZero[i]) {
                transformRow(i, matrix);
            }
        }

        // Iterate through columnsWithZero and transform all columns with 0 to 0.

        for (int i = 0; i < columnsWithZero.length; i++) {
            if (columnsWithZero[i]) {
                transformColumn(i, matrix);
            }
        }


        return matrix;

    }

    private static void transformColumn(int column, int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            matrix[row][column] = 0;
        }
    }

    private static void transformRow(int row, int[][] matrix) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[0].length; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Related question](/q/136226/9357)

Answer (score 2):

## comments

Comments should say **why** the code is like it is. Any other information to the reader should be given to the reader by the *identifiers* to chose.

Your comments structure the method in 3 logical sections (the first without a dedicated comment). You should better move this three sections into separate methods with names derived from the comments:

```
private static int[][] setZeroes(int[][] matrix) {
    boolean[] rowsWithZero = new boolean[matrix.length];
    boolean[] columnsWithZero = new boolean[matrix[0].length];

    findZeros(matrix,rowsWithZero,columnsWithZero);
    transformColumns(matrix,columnsWithZero);
    transformRows(matrix,rowsWithZero);

    return matrix;
}
private static void findZeros(int[][] matrix, boolean[] rowsWithZero, boolean[] columnsWithZero){
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                rowsWithZero[i] = true;
                columnsWithZero[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void transformColumns(int[][] matrix,  boolean[] columnsWithZero){
    for (int i = 0; i < columnsWithZero.length; i++) {
        if (columnsWithZero[i]) {
            transformColumn(i, matrix);
        }
    }
}
private static void transformRows(int[][] matrix, boolean[] rowsWithZero){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsWithZero.length; i++) {
        if (rowsWithZero[i]) {
            transformRow(i, matrix);
        }
    }
}
```